# Android OneSignal disable reciving notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, onesignal

In my android application i have two user roles (admin & user).

First of all i send the TAG to the OneSignal with:
    OneSignal.sendTag("role",user.getRole());

i want that

1. the user can send notifications to all admin users the admin users
2. can send notifications to all (users and admins)

in this 2° case the admin how send a notifications he recive  that notifications.

i try this code:

```
        OneSignal.setSubscription(false);
        sendNotifWithRetrofit(itemPosition);
        OneSignal.setSubscription(true);
```

but it don't work

i also tried the way with AsyncTask to make sure the:

```
        OneSignal.setSubscription(false);
```

is running before the :

```
        sendNotifWithRetrofit(itemPosition);
```

and after that :

```
        OneSignal.setSubscription(true);
```

inside onPostExecute

what is the best way to do this.